# Relative Variance

Tags: variance, terminology

Is there a standard definition of the **Relative Variance**? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_standard_deviation) defines it as the square of the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation), but some [articles](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch2/rel_var.pdf) define it as the variance divided by the absolute value of the mean. I tend to like Wikipedia's definition best, because it is nondimensional, but I cannot find any thorough analysis of its properties.

$RV = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{\overline{x}^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{\overline{x}^2}$

Comment: Perhaps the Wikipedia page has changed since this question was posted, but it does not currently define relative variance to be squared CV. I think the short answer is that no, there is no widely accepted definition of "relative variance". Presented with that term, I think most statisticians would ask: "relative to what?". I think you are free to define the term as you want, provided that you make your usage clear.

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the terminology problem is questionable self-consistency. For example, let us propose one plausibly self-consistent approach to relative variance. Such a system would have the property that the logarithms of the data are normally distributed, that is, that the errors of measurement are proportional type. Then, the anti-logarithms of the average logarithm of the independent or dependent variables would be good measures of location. Also, the relative measurements are then normally distributed such that transformed $\bar{x}_{new}$ and $\sigma_{new}$ become dimensionless.

In terms of the original data, for a proportional system, $$RV = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{\bar{x}_{new}} -1 \right)^2 = \sigma^2 \; .$$ In a more general context, what relative variance means depends on the distribution types of the data, and, for some distributions, it is not as useful a concept as for other distributions.